# how to write ```border: 1px solid transparent;``` in tailwind css

Tags: css, user-interface, tailwind-css, tailwind-ui

How do I write `border: 1px solid transparent;` in tailwind css? I couldn't find a way in the docs of tailwind.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this,

```css
<div class="border-solid border-1 border-transparent"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks it worked!
Also another issue i was facing was % like `width: 10%;` how could I do that in tailwind?

Comment: If this works please mark this as the answer. I think tailwind divide the section into 12 parts so idk if there is a way to get exactly 10%. you can get closer using `w-1/12` check more on docs. https://tailwindcss.com/docs/width

Comment: Thanks worked! i also marked it as ur ans!

Answer (score 0):

According to Tailwind's [border width](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/border-width) documentation, a `1px` border should be specified with just `border`, not `border-1` like most other utilities.

In full, `border-solid border-1 border-transparent`